# Restangular and Asp.Net WebApi Post

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, restangular

I am trying to call Asp.Net WebApi method declared as:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login2")]
    public bool Login(UserInfo userinfo)
    {
        return userinfo.Username == "sandeep@sa.com" && userinfo.Password == "chandra";
    }
```

And from Restangular the code looks like:

```
var lUserInfo = { Username: this.fEmail, Password: this.fPassword };
this.fLoginService.withConfig(x => x.setDefaultHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }))
    .all("v1Values").post("Login2", null,
        { userinfo: lUserInfo }).then(
            x => {
                var lLoggedIn: boolean = x == "true";
                this.fSessionService.fUserAuthenticated = lLoggedIn;
                if (lLoggedIn) {
                    this.fLocation.path('/dashboard');
                    return;
                }

                Utilities.Dialog.showError('Invalid Email or Password');
        });
```

I get this error:

```
"OPTIONS http://myserver:7220/api/v1Values 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

I just can't get this to work. I can't see userinfo passed in the body.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ActionName is not part of web.api... Can you show us your routing configuration and your Controller

Comment: ActionName is part of Web API. See: System.Web.Http.ActionNameAttribute.

Is the issue that the action is being hit, but there is no data in the body? You should probably mark [FromBody] on the UserInfo

Comment: I think you need custompost

Comment: I have tried customPOST as well but it doesn't work. I think Restangular cannot pass content in body when doing a POST. I think it might be time to give up on Restangular and look for something else.